# DownloadAsyncData of WebClient fails

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-3.5, download, webclient

I have  a url in the format http://ww.url.com/page?id=200. This will download a file of 10 MB. However i am getting the e.ProgressPercentage as 0 always. but it is hitting the upload done function with the actual results read.

Please tell me what i am doing wrong here.

I am using the following code

```
private void button1_Click(object
    sender, EventArgs e)
{

    WebClient webClient = new WebClientEx();

    webClient.DownloadProgressChanged +=
        new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(wc_DownloadProgressChanged);

    webClient.DownloadDataCompleted += new
        DownloadDataCompletedEventHandler(wc_DownloadComplete);

    webClient.DownloadDataAsync(new Uri("http://ww.url.com/page?id=200"));


}

public void wc_DownloadProgressChanged(Object sender, 
    DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)

{
    Progress1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage; // this is 0
}

public void wc_DownloadComplete(Object sender,DownloadDataCompletedEventArgs e)

{
    int a = 0;
    this.Close();
}
} }
```

Comment: Maybe it's caused by your formatting (-:)

Comment: And caution: Your CompletedEvent lacks errorhandling.

Answer (score 0):

ProgressPercentage is based on the ContentLength returned in the header of the response. If the response doesn't know how big the download will be when it is putting together the header, you won't be able to get the progress.

If this was simply a file returned by IIS, IIS would get the size of the file from the file system and set the header for you. If the response is dynamic and fit within the buffer, the length of the response could be set. However, I am fairly certain the default buffer size is less than 10MB so the response header is sent back to the client before the length of the response is known.

In Asp.Net, you would do this (where you put it depends on your platform)...

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", "10485760");
```